# Property 'key' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>' ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am unable to use key as prop to components when I am doing the usual map rendering

```
const sample = ['a', 'b', 'c']

{sample.map(_, index => (
 <button key={index}/>
))}
```

I tried inspecting the problem within index.d.ts but I am a beginner and did not know what to look for. I have @types/react and @types/react-dom installed at latest. In case this info is necessary, my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from "react";

const sample = ['a', 'b', 'c']

{sample.map((value, index) => (
  <button key={index}>{value}</button>
))}
```

Based on the provided code snippet in the question,

- please check the opening and closing braces.
- please check the signature of `array.map` function.
- verify if you have imported React at the top.

P.S. - not recommended to use array index as keys - https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#rules-of-keys

Comment: The braces are proper in my code, it is typo in this post. Thank you for pointing that out. React is imported correctly, the signature is proper also in my code, I did not have this problem until I started integrating typescript to my project. I think typescript is saying it does not expect HTML elements to an attribute of 'key'